# QuickTime plugin not found when I play a movie using Safari on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, plugins, quicktime, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0 (7A341)/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin" (file not found).
```

I'm not sure, but this causes the movie to take a long time to load.

What I mean by play a movie using Safari is that I use the **Safari's QuickTime plugin** to play it. I tried to use **MPMoviePlayerController** but it *doesn't work* with **m4v** types of movies. This is the code that I use.

```
UIViewController *playViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 

UIViewController *playViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
UIWebView *playMusicWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
[playMusicWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString]]];
[playViewController.view addSubview: playMusicWebView];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:playViewController animated: NO];  
[playMusicWebView release];
```

The movie takes forever to load. Is there any way to add the correct plugin for PhoneOS's internet QuickTime player?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on the actual device or in the simulator?

If you're in the sim, that's likely your problem...video won't play there.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem 
Actually it is not the problem with code, it is due to the simulator which donot support such type of plugins

You should try this code on device it completely works fine

Answer (score 0):

It being unable to read symbols shouldn't have anything to do with your performance. The symbols just refer to debugging symbols which would allow you to debug any error within the plugins. It won't affect the performance of your app, since it's unrelated.